Bruhat Order of the Finite Symmetric Group
I am studying Theorem 2.1.5 in "Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups", but I am confused by a statement in the proof of the "if" direction (the part after $\textbf{However}$). Let me quote the theorem and the proof below:

Theorem 2.1.5:
Let $x,y\in S_n$. Then $x\leq y \iff x[i,j]\leq y[i,j]$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$
(Notations: $[n]$ means $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. On LHS, $\leq$ denotes the Bruhat order. On RHS, $x[i,j] := |\{a\in [i]:x(a)\geq j\}|$.)

Proof for $\left(\impliedby\right)$:
Assume $x[i,j]\leq y[i,j]$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$.
Let $M(i,j)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} y[i,j]-x[i,j]$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$.
If $M(i,j)=0$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$, then $x=y$.
Let $(a_1,b_1)\in [n]^2$ be such that $M(a_1,b_1)>0$ and $M(i,j)=0$ $\forall (i,j)\in[1,a_1]\times[b_1,n]\setminus\{(a_1,b_1)\}$.
Then $y(a_1)=b_1$ and $x(a_1)<b_1$.
Now, let $(a_2,b_2)\in [n]^2$ be the bottom right corner of a maximal positive connected submatrix of $M$ having $(a_1,b_1)$ as the upper left corner.
Since $x[n,j]=y[n,j]=n+1-j$ and $x[i,1]=y[i,1]=i$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$, we have $a_2<n$ and $b_2>1$.
By maximality, there exist $c\in [a_1,a_2]$ and $d\in [b_2,b_1]$ such that $M(c,b_2-1)=0=M(a_2+1,d)$.
Hence, $M(a_2+1,b_2-1)-M(c,b_2-1)-M(a_2+1,d)+M(c,d)>0$.
This means $|\{e\in [c+1,a_2+1]:y(e)\in [b_2-1,d-1]\}|>0$ .
So there exists some $(a_0,b_0)\in [c+1,a_2+1]\times [b_2-1,d-1]$ be such that $y(a_0)=b_0$.
Then $a_1<a_0$ and $y(a_1)=b_1>b_0=y(a_0)$. So, $z\longrightarrow y$, where $z\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}y\cdot (a_1,a_0)$.
$\textbf{ However}$, by $\left(\ast\right)$ and our choice of $(a_2,b_2)$, we have $x[i,j]\leq z[i,j]$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$.
Hence, by induction, we get $x\leq z$ and therefore $x\leq y$.
The statement $\left(\ast\right)$ refers to:
If $y=x\cdot (a,b)$ and $x(a)<x(b)$ for some $1\leq a<b\leq n$, then $y[i,j]= \begin{cases} x[i,j]+1 & \text{if }a\leq i<b, x(a)<j\leq x(b) \\ x[i,j] & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$


I am particularly confused about the use of $\left(\ast\right)$. It should be putting $x=z, a=a_1, b=a_0$ into $\left(\ast\right)$, because $z$ preserves the order of $a_1<a_0$ while $y$ does not. But then this will lead to $z[i,j]\leq y[i,j]$ $\forall i,j\in [n]$. I guess we should arrive at this inequality with the sign reversed, so that $x[i,j]\leq y[i,j]\leq z[i,j]$.
Can anyone correct me on this? Many thanks!
